# ¿Cómo quito un directorio que añadí a Git con "git add"?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, git-bash

En Git Bash por error escribí directamente el comando:

```
add .
```

sin antes haber puesto el comando `cd y el nombre de mi proyecto`.

Por tal motivo al abrir visual studio en el Team Explorer se cargó la carpeta C:\Users\ con todos los archivos (que son miles de archivos).

¿Cómo hago para cancelarlo desde git Bash o directamente desde visual?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Git Bash puedes utilizar `git reset`. Esto 'desestabilizará' todos los archivos que ha agregado después de su último commit.

Si quieres borrar solo algunos archivos, use `git reset -- <file 1> <file 2> <file n>`.

También es posible borrar algunos de los cambios en los archivos usando `git reset -p`.

Answer (score 1):

Con las nuevas versiones de Git puedes decir:

```
git restore --staged directorio/
```

---

Ejemplo completo añadiendo un archivo "hola":

```
$ touch hola
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    hola

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git add hola

$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   hola

$ git restore --staged hola

$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    hola

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```